# Pandas giving memory error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the code that goes to almost 10K+ csv files and each file has almost 16K + lines having multiple columns. I run the code and after 5 minutes I got this below error. I can understand that if I set low_memory=False, it will suppress error. But how to fix this issue ? 
The error seems coming because of below. Can it be fixed?

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'] 

DtypeWarning: Columns (9,11,12,13,14) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 705, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 451, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1083, in read
    df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 330, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 461, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6140, in _arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4632, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4704, in form_blocks
    int_blocks = _multi_blockify(int_items)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4773, in _multi_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(list(tup_block), dtype)
  File "\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4816, in _stack_arrays
    stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Maybe set `dtype` to a list of corresponding data types for your column values during import? If this is not explicitly set, pandas will require more space to guess the data types, which is not possible on low memory setting.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your total data's size isn't of the same magnitude of your total RAM.

I have made similar errors when working with a dataset of ~10GB (on a computer with 16GB RAM) and running multiple tabs on Chrome at the same time.

If that happens, try deleting your dataframes after processing them and before reading the next csv file:

```
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for file in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    process(df)    
    del(df)
```

OBS: Normally you need 10x as much RAM as the data you are working with to be able to work fluidly in pandas.

Comment: I have ~12 G of csv, 8G RAM . While running script RAM was sufficiently available.

Comment: @steveJ You have 12gb data but only 8 gb RAM?

Comment: Is 8G RAM not sufficient to do operations for 8 G at a time ? I am just picking few columns based on some condition and putting that in new csv.